# Railscast authorization from scratch for users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authorization, cancan, railscasts

So this is the authorization code I wrote based on [Railscast #386](http://railscasts.com/episodes/386-authorization-from-scratch-part-2?autoplay=true).

The problem is that the block works on all controllers except for `user_controller`. In other words, any user can triger `edit` and `update` actions on any other user, even though the block given to it is the same as that of favors `edit` and `update` actions.

```
def initialize(user)
    allow :users, [:new, :create, :show]
    allow :sessions, [:new, :create, :destroy]
    allow :favors, [:index, :show]
    if user
      allow :users, [:edit, :update] do |usr|
        usr.id == user.id
      end
      allow :favors, [:new, :create]
      allow :favors, [:edit, :update] do |favor|
        favor.user_id == user.id
      end
      allow :acceptances, [:create, :update] do |acceptance|
        !acceptance.has_accepted_acceptance?
      end
    end
  end
```

Any help is highly appreciated :)

Comment: [It is available on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GE-4chF3Tu0) for anyone who doesn't have a RailsCasts subscription

Comment: Are you authorizing the `@user` in the users controller?

Comment: I am passing `current_user` in a method called `current_resource` in `users_controller` which is overwriting `current_resource` method in `application_controller` which is then passed as an object to the `Permission` class. The problem is that I guess `current_resource` in users is not overwriting the one in `application_controller`

Comment: is there a reason why usr.id is used instead of user.id?

Answer (score 0):

You are already passing in the `(user)` to the permission class.  By calling it again in

`if user... do |user|... end`

you are re-initializing the passed-in user, making it `nil`.  You then try to give a nil user permissions on the controller#action, in this case anything involving the user's account.

The reason Ryan Bates includes a block in permissions involving other models is because the model instance hasn't been passed to the permission class.  That is why you see the likes of:

```
allow_action :topics, [:new, :create, :index]
allow_action :topics, [:edit, :update, :show] do |topic|
  topic.author_id == user.id
end
allow_attr :topic, [:title, :content]
```

This bit above grants permissions on all the topics the user may or has created.

**SOLUTION**  Take out anything that re-initializes the `(user)` and then try again.

```
allow_action :users, [:edit, :update]
allow_attr :users, [:email, :invite_token, :name, :surname, :password, :password_confirmation]
```

**NOTE** I have renamed the `allow` action to `allow_action`, as per Ryan's suggestion in the Railscast.  I also renamed the `allow_param` method to `allow_attr` since we are used to using attr_accessible anyway.