# Two separate dashboard based on condition - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My app has `Users` and `accounts`. Then there is the has_many though table called `account_memberships` on that table I have an admin attribute that is a boolean. Here is my question If a someone creates a user that has the admin attribute set to `false` how can I have them only see a particular page? Should I set some method in the application controller that I can use for a before_action?

Comment: Yes. :) Why don't you have a go at that and see how it goes. implement it naively at first, then improve it

Comment: What you are trying to do is Authorization. This [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan) is a little old, but can be useful - but you should use [CanCanCan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) instead of CanCan, or see [Ruby Toolbox](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_authorization), or just create your own [authorization from scratch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35120915/railscast-authorization-from-scratch-for-users).

Comment: This [Pundit gem](https://github.com/elabs/pundit) may also help you. It is very easy to use.